# Do gods and fairies not blink?

Tags: gods, goddess

Few years before I read an article which belongs to some fairies story. And I came to know that fairies/god's/deities doesn't blink like as human. Is it true or an artificial story? If it is true, can someone  provide a reference if any scriptures are available?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is true. Gods do not blink. There are four physical qualities of Gods which differentiate them from humans.

1. They do not blink. Hence they are called Animisha.
2. They do not sweat.
3. Their feet do not touch ground. There is a thin gap between the surface and their feet.
4. Shadow is not formed for them.

   These are the qualities which Damayanti used to differentiate Nala from deities, Varuna, Indra, Agni and Yama when they disguised themselves as Nala Maharaja during Swayamvaram.

   Excerpt from [chapter 57](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03057.htm) of Nalopakhyana Parva, Vana Parva (Emphasis mine)

   > O, let the gods reveal him unto me, O, let the exalted guardians of the worlds assume their own proper forms, so that I may know the righteous king.' Hearing these piteous words of Damayanti, and ascertaining her fixed resolve, and fervent love for the king of Nishadhas, the purity of her heart and her inclination and regard and affection for Nala, **the gods did as they had been adjured, and assumed their respective attributes as best they could**. And thereupon **she beheld the celestials unmoistened with perspiration, with winkless eyes, and unfading garlands, unstained with dust, and staying without touching the ground**. And Naishadha stood revealed to his shadow, his fading garlands, himself stained with dust and sweat, resting on the ground with winking eyes.

   Unfading garlands is a specific quality of Varuna which is also a boon bestowed by him to Nala Maharaja later.

Comment: Need to find those aliens from MIB perspective.

Comment: It might be true that some scriptures say these things, but it's not true in the real sense that you or I do exist.  I've read something that says the leader of North Korea does not defecate because his body is in such complete balance, but I don't believe it, do you?

Comment: Neil, you're free to choose what to believe. First of all, how do you REALLY KNOW that I exist ? Maybe I am just a highly advanced robot/simulation. You just choose to believe that I exist.

Answer (score 11):

According to the Devi Bhagavata Purana 6.15 (Book 6, Chapter 15), twinkling of eyes do not happen for the Devas. They have a fixed gaze. In contrast, for human beings, beasts etc the blinking of eyes occur.

> ” The Devî, the Lord of the Devas, the Mother of the World being
>   highly pleased, said thus :-- “O King! At the expiry of this your
>   Prârabdha Karma, you will acquire pure knowledge and you will reside
>   on the tops of the eyes in the shape of Vâyu, and through your
>   residing there the beings will twinkle, i.e., open and close their
>   eyes. The men, beasts, and birds will twinkle due to your residing
>   there; **but the Immortals will always remain with a steadfast gaze;
>   they will not twinkle.**” 
>    Thus granting him the boon, and addressing all the Munis the
>   Bhagavatî, the Highest Deity, disappeared.

So, it seems also that only after this above mentioned boon started to take effect, the beings that blink, started to do so. So, probably there was a time when nobody used to blink eyes :).

However, at many places of the same Purana, as well as elsewhere, it is stated that the Divine Mother performs the tasks of creation/destruction etc with a blink of her eyes. So, some kind of confusion is there it seems or may be we should not take that blinking of Devi's eyes literally.

> 1-4. S’rî Nârada said :-- **In the twinkling of an eye of the Devî, the
>   Pralaya takes place; and in that very time also the Brahmânda (cosmos)
>   is dissolved**, which is called the Pralaya of Prakriti. During this
>   Pralaya, the Devî Vasundharâ (Earth) disappears; the whole world is
>   deluged with water and all this appearance of five elements called
>   Prapañcha vanishes in the body of Prakriti.

This passage is from the Devi Bhagavata Purana 9.8.